# NEO4J BoltConnectionError: No connection found, did you connect to Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j , using Desktop (3.4.1 Enterprise Version). 
I have used LOAD CSV utility executed from Cypher Shell Command close to 1 Million records in the file. I have monitored the load using Neo4j browser by monitoring the count of properties and relationships that was created. Every time the load stops with the error "BoltConnectionError: No connection found, did you connect to Neo4j?" . I have also tried monitoring through the browser localhost:7474 - the error is different "server connection time out.. " , but the end result is that the load CSV fails to completed. Could someone please advise or guide me what needs to be done to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be loading along with [USING PERIODIC COMMIT](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) when loading data to batch the load and avoid killing your heap.

Also, you may want to EXPLAIN your query and ensure your load is using index lookups, especially if you're doing MERGEs on node properties.

In your query plan, watch out for Eager operations, that will effectively kill your periodic commit approach (and the browser should warn you with that query if it's in the query box prior to executing). You should include your query here for analysis and troubleshooting (along with the query plan) if the previous advice isn't enough to help you pinpoint the issue.

Comment: thanks - I have used periodic commits. As you have pointed out - Eager Operations were our problem.. We have tuned our query and able to run the batch load.